# Getting error create partition range partition table using function...

Tags: greenplum, hawq

Wanted to create partition table but getting syntax error:

CREATE TABLE public.emp (id int, date_1 date, amt decimal(10,2))
DISTRIBUTED BY (id)
PARTITION BY RANGE (extract(year from date_1)::int)
( START ('2008') INCLUSIVE
   END ('2010') EXCLUSIVE
   EVERY (INTERVAL '1 year') 
   );

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 3: PARTITION BY RANGE (extract(year from date_1)::int)
                                   ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
SQL state: 42601
Character: 117

Answer (score 1):

'partition by range' expects a column name as key.
Try:
partition by range (date_1) 
(START (date '2008-01-01') INCLUSIVE
   END (date '2009-01-01') EXCLUSIVE
   EVERY (INTERVAL '1 year')
)

Comment: Thanks,Yes you are correct If I remove the extract function its work fine but how could I achieve the above one means I need only year YYYY to create partition.

Comment: that's in the last tag "EVERY (INTERVAL '1 year'). You can give name to each partition like this.

partition by range (date_1) (PARTITION year2008 START (date '2008-01-01') INCLUSIVE END (date '2009-01-01') EXCLUSIVE EVERY (INTERVAL '1 year') )

Comment: but in this case partition name will be emp_1_prt_2008_1 then emp_1_prt_2008_2 so on ... but I need name should be display like emp_1_prt_2008 then emp_1_prt_2009 so on ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a name to each partition, then you have to give explicitly each partition name.

```
CREATE TABLE public.emp (id int, date_1 date, amt decimal(10,2)) 
DISTRIBUTED BY (id) 
partition by range (date_1) 
(partition year2008 START (date '2008-01-01') INCLUSIVE,
 partition year2009 START (date '2009-01-01') INCLUSIVE,
 partition year2010 START (date '2010-01-01') INCLUSIVE
    END (date '2011-01-01') EXCLUSIVE EVERY (INTERVAL '1 year') );
```

Then following three partition tables will be created.

```
public.emp_1_prt_year2008
public.emp_1_prt_year2009
public.emp_1_prt_year2010
```

Comment: But I have only date_1 column and wanted to create partition yearly and subpartition of specific year on monthly

Comment: Some thing like this

CREATE TABLE sales (id int, year int, month int, day int, region text)
DISTRIBUTED BY (id)
PARTITION BY RANGE (year)
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (month)
SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE (
START (1) END (13) EVERY (1),
DEFAULT SUBPARTITION other_months )
( START (2002) END (2010) EVERY (1),
DEFAULT PARTITION outlying_years );

but in this table they have year and month but I have only date_1 column and wanted to create partition yearly and subpartition of specific year on monthly

Comment: Is there is a way to use function in Partition syntax something like  PARTITION BY RANGE (date_part('year',date_1))
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (date_part('month',date_1))

Answer (score 0):

We need to manually mention name to each partition. This will create partition by year and subpartition by month.

```
CREATE TABLE emp (id int, date_1 date, amt decimal(10,2))
DISTRIBUTED BY (id)
partition by range (date_1)
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (date_1)
(
    PARTITION year_2008 START ('2008-01-01'::date) INCLUSIVE END ('2009-01-01'::date)
 ( 
   SUBPARTITION mnth_jan START ('2008-01-01'::date) INCLUSIVE,
   SUBPARTITION mnth_feb START ('2008-02-01'::date) INCLUSIVE
   END ('2008-03-01'::date)
 ),
    PARTITION year_2009 START ('2009-01-01'::date) INCLUSIVE END ('2010-01-01'::date)
 ( 
   SUBPARTITION mnth_jan START ('2009-01-01'::date) INCLUSIVE,
   SUBPARTITION mnth_feb START ('2009-02-01'::date) INCLUSIVE
   END ('2009-03-01'::date)
 )
 );
```